# pipfile not found from deeper subdirectories

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

Is there a directory-depth limit on the auto-location of pipfile? I have a three-level directory structure in my project and I'm finding that `pipenv` commands from any tier-three (or deeper) directory don't know that they're already part of a pipenv project.

Here's a demonstration:

```bash
$ env -i sh -l
$ mkdir /tmp/myproject
$ cd /tmp/myproject
$ pipenv --where
No Pipfile present at project home. Consider running `pipenv install` first to automatically generate a Pipfile for you.

$ touch Pipfile
$ pipenv --where
/tmp/myproject

$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d

$ cd a
$ pipenv --where  
/tmp/myproject

$ cd b
$ pipenv --where
/tmp/myproject

$ cd c
$ pipenv --where
No Pipfile present at project home. Consider running `pipenv install` first to automatically generate a Pipfile for you.

$ cd d
$ pipenv --where
No Pipfile present at project home. Consider running `pipenv install` first to automatically generate a Pipfile for you.
```

You can see here that in subdirectories at depths of one or two pipenv will honor the parent pipfile, but deeper directories seem to disable that behavior.

Is this a bug or a feature? I read the docs a good deal and even debugged pipenv to try to pinpoint the cause, but found nothing relevant.

---

Debug details:

```bash
$ pipenv --support
Pipenv version: `'2022.7.4'`
Pipenv location: `'/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv'`
Python location: `'/usr/bin/python'`
Python installations found:

  - `3.10.5`: `/usr/bin/python`
  - `3.10.5`: `/usr/bin/python3`

PEP 508 Information:

`` `
{'implementation_name': 'cpython',
 'implementation_version': '3.10.5',
 'os_name': 'posix',
 'platform_machine': 'x86_64',
 'platform_python_implementation': 'CPython',
 'platform_release': '5.10.120-16471-g167ad2e5dcba',
 'platform_system': 'Linux',
 'platform_version': '#1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 29 18:58:29 PDT 2022',
 'python_full_version': '3.10.5',
 'python_version': '3.10',
 'sys_platform': 'linux'}
`` `

System environment variables:

  - `LESSCHARSET`
  - `EDITOR`
  - `PWD`
  - `LANG`
  - `VISUAL`
  - `SHLVL`
  - `PATH`
  - `_`
  - `OLDPWD`
  - `LC_CTYPE`
  - `PIP_SHIMS_BASE_MODULE`
  - `PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK`
  - `PIP_PYTHON_PATH`
  - `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`
  - `PYTHONFINDER_IGNORE_UNSUPPORTED`

Pipenv–specific environment variables:

(none)

Debug–specific environment variables:

  - `PATH`: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`
  - `EDITOR`: `nvim`
  - `LANG`: `en_US.UTF-8`
  - `PWD`: `/tmp/myproject/a/b/c/d`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the advantage of having an open source project, where you can go look at the source.  Yes, the maximum search depth is 2.

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/main/pipenv/project.py#L444

You can override the depth using an environment variable, PIPENV_MAX_DEPTH.